# How to configure Babel when unit testing a Sanity Studio project

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, babeljs, sanity

I'm using [`sanity.io`](https://sanity.io) as a headless CMS and am trying to unit test some of my code.  Sanity internally uses [`babel`](https://babeljs.io) to pre-compile the source code.

For my unit tests I am using [`mocha`](https://mochajs.org) and am invoking it with the following script (in `package.json`)

```
"scripts": {
  "test:unit": "find ./test/unit -name '*.spec.js' | NODE_ENV=test xargs mocha --require babel-core/register --require ./test/unit/testHelper.js"
},
```

If I add my own `.babelrc` file to the root of my project then the tests work, but running `sanity start` fails.

The `.babelrc` file I am using contains

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

If I don't add my own `.babelrc` file then `sanity start` works but the tests fail as `babel` is not being configured.

How can I tell `babel` to only use a specific config when I am running tests.

Comment: So you have a Sanity Content Studio. And some custom code in that studio. And you want to unit test that custom code? If yes, and you're running into babel issues would it be an option to isolate that testable code (I presume it's not react components) into a separate and easily testable code repo? That would grant you independence of all Sanity specific configs.

Comment: my code includes a react component.  I ended up having a pretest script that copies in the `.babelrc` file I need for the tests, then removes it again after the test has run.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working!